# Bing Custom Event - Click Button

Tags: javascript, events, bing

I keep finding this place while searching for answers to javascript so I just made an account here.

I'm a noob. I don't know much about coding. Hardly anything.

I'm usually really good with reading tutorials and watching videos instead of asking questions on forums, but I've come across something I can't figure out.

I'm using Bing and I want to be able to track button clicks on my website using their javascript tag. I have installed the basic javascript in my inside the , but I don't understand anything of their custom events.

This is what Bing says:

"JavaScript UET Tag
If you have JavaScript UET Tag, you will need to add the following custom event JavaScript to the UET tag tracking code:

```
<script>
window.uetq = window.uetq || []; 
window.uetq.push
({ 'ec':'Event category', 'ea':'Event action', 'el':'Event label', 'ev':'Event value' }); 
</script>"
```

Okay... and that's basically all I get from Bing. No examples of how to add a simple button, so I don't know what to do.

There's this too:
"Step 1: Reporting custom events using UET: There are 4 parameters that advertisers can report when logging custom events.
Event category: The category of the event you want to track. For example, 'video
Event action: The type of user interaction you want to track. For example, 'play' or 'pause'
Event label: The name of the element that caused the action. For example, 'trailer' or 'behindthescenes'
Event value: A numerical value associated with that event. For example, the length of the video played
The event value can be any value from 0 to 9999999 with 3 decimal fields."

On my website I have a button that I've located in the code.
It goes like this:

```
<button id="surveyAgree" class="stepButton yesBtn" href="<?php echo $agreeLink;?>">I AGREE!</button>
```

I want clicks on that button to be a custom event, but I have no clue how to make that happen. Can a kind soul in this place reveal the secrets to making this happen?

Thanks for listening.

Jon